# Unable to understand program work flow

Tags: java, constructor

```
// filename: Test2.java
class Test1 {   
    Test1(int x) {
        System.out.println("Constructor called " + x);
    }
}

// This class contains an instance of Test1 
class Test2 {    
    Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);   

    Test2(int i) { t1 = new Test1(i); } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
         Test2 t2 = new Test2(5);
    }
}

Output:
Constructor called 10
Constructor called 5
```

Can anyone pls explain me the output of this program?
I am not able to get how "**Constructor called 10**" is getting printed.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I debugged the program already, but I am not sure if I am missing any concept here.Like hitting t1 inside the constructor of Test2, it moves to the line where t1 is assigned the object reference of Test1 :(. t1 is just a reference variable why constructor of Test1 is getting called.Please excuse me if am sounding dull.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Your main invokes the constructor of `Test2`.
- Before the body of that constructor is executed, all the instance variables of that class are initialized.
- This includes `Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);` which executes the constructor of `Test1` with the argument 10 and prints "Constructor called 10".
- Only then the body of the `Test2` constructor is executed, which includes `t1 = new Test1(i);`, which executes the constructor of `Test1` with the argument `i` (whose value is 5) and prints "Constructor called 5".

Comment: ahh! got it.before executing constructor, first instance variables are initialized.Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

In your Test2 class you have created an instance of Test1 by calling Test1's constructor and passing in a value of 10.

```
Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);
```

Inside it's constructor is a print statement that prints the value passed into the constructor.

```
Test1(int x) {
    System.out.println("Constructor called " + x);
}
```

This is where your output is coming from.